# load custom field that are not part of model to the database

Tags: django

How should data from a custom field, that are not part of a model be loaded to the database? 
I have this model

**model-CompoundSynonym**

```
compound = models.ForeignKey('MDictionary', blank=False, null=True)
synonym_type = models.ForeignKey('SynonymType')
synonym_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, help_text=u'Synonym for the compound')


 def __unicode__(self):
     return u'%s' % (self.synonym_name)
```

And I have a form.py to add a custom field to the model. The custom field is a fileField that takes a text file with synonym_names. This custom field is to enable loading more than one synonym_name for a particular compound and synonym_type.

**The model text file**

```
Rege574574
Rege337483
Rege394837
Rege348389
```

In theory whenever I click save from the adminx page I want the file to be parsed and the synonym_name from the file be inserted for a particular compound, synonym_type.

But in my case the synonym_name in the original (model)form is loaded(which is empty when  I give a file)

This is what I have :

**form.py**

```
class CompoundSynonymForm(ModelForm):
    file_upload = FileField(required=False)
    print "YES"


    def save(self, commit=True):

        file_upload = self.cleaned_data.get('file_upload', None)
        print file_upload

        with open("../../Downloads/model_file_upload.txt", 'r') as f:
            print "here "
            model_file = File(f)
            names = model_file.read()
            name_list = names.split('\n')
            for each_name in name_list:
               if each_name != 'Header':  
                 <this is where I have to save them>

        class Meta:
           model = CompoundSynonym
```

I get the file parse and the names from the file but I couldn't save them to the Database. How should I overwrite the synonym_name from the modelform to my names from file?

**UPDATE**

```
with open("../../Downloads/model_file_upload.txt", 'r') as f:
            print "here "
            model_file = File(f)
            names = model_file.read()
            name_list = names.split('\n')
            for each_name in name_list:
                if each_name != 'Header':
                    obj = super(CompoundSynonymForm, self).save(commit=False)
                    obj.synonym_name = each_name
                    if commit:
                        obj.save()
                    return obj
```

**This saves just the first line of the file.**

Comment: what exactly is it that you want in your database? Can you post the full model and the full form please

Comment: I have posted the full form and full model

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing within the `with` block doesn't really make a lot of sense. You instantiate a new form object, for some reason, passing it the names you've parsed from the file in the place of the usual POST data. Then, you modify the synonym_name of your model *class* itself with that same list of names. Finally, you ignore all of that and call the existing form's superclass save method.

Instead of all that, what you want to do is simply modify the object that is returned from the superclass save, assigning your list of names:

```
with open("../../Downloads/model_file_upload.txt", 'r') as f:
    model_file = File(f)
    names = model_file.read()
obj = super(CompoundSynonymForm, self).save(commit=False)
obj.synonym_name = names
if commit:
    obj.save()
return obj
```

Although I'm not totally sure this is what you want to do; I presume you actually want to scan through the file to find the synonym that matches the foreign key value, but you haven't shown any code to do that.

Comment: I want to save the names from the file to the database for the given synonym-type. example : synonym_type == Rege and compound name is 'XYZ' all the data from the file should be linked to the Compound 'XYZ' and synonym_type 'Rege'.

Comment: But your `synonym_name` field is only 50 characters long. How much data is in a file?

Comment: It might have 100s of names. They have split by a new line character. each name wouldn't be more than 50 character long.

Comment: So you're saying you want to create one CompoundSynonym object for *each* line in the file? Why didn't you say that from the start, and how did you expect your original code to do that?

Comment: See my edited code in forms.py. Sorry I should have added as soon as I figured out that names is giving me the whole file.  Sorry new to python and Django. Learning by trial and error.